# Vapor Xcode project structure off

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

I'm making my way through the [vapor](https://vapor.codes) tutorial [videos](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-getting-started/) [on](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-templating-with-leaf) [Ray](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-configuring-a-database) [Wenderlich's](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-persisting-models) [site](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-crud-database-options).

In the Xcode project in the videos, it shows a nice clean folder structure, like how the folder structure is defined in the [vapor docs](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/folder-structure.html).
[image]

When I follow the same steps to create a new vapor project and use xcode as the docs and videos show, `vapor new my-project` -> `cd my-project` -> `vapor xcode`. 
The folder structure I see is not the same.
[image]

The folder structure I see (above) I can use just fine. However, when I open the `Sources` folder(group) I see all the vapor dependencies listed instead of just the `App` folder.
[image]
... and on until finally the last folder listed is the `App` folder.

Running this command `curl -sL check.vapor.sh | bash` I can see that my vapor installation was successful.
I'm using `Vapor Toolbox v1.0.3` and `Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)`

**Does anyone know how to use** `vapor xcode` **and have it generate an Xcode project where the vapor dependencies don't show up in the** `Sources` **folder?**

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Its doing my nut in :)

Comment: @Vade the below answer is the correct reason why it's happening. As for how to fix it, I'm waiting a little while longer to see if the folder structure is updated in a new version of Swift. Until then we just have to deal with the folder structure like that :/

Answer (score 1):

This was reported as a bug, see https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/777.

Comment: Ah, good find. So I'd need the latest SwiftPM release here?https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/releases
Is the way to download the latest SwiftPM release to download the latest Swift snapshot release or preview?